# How can I convert this unique string of characters into a unique number?

Tags: hash-function

I have an unusual programming problem and the math side of it has me stumped. It's probably a simple answer but math isn't my strongest area.

I've generated a unique string of 7 characters which are each randomly selected from these possibilities: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789` for example `A6HJ92B` and I need to convert it to a unique number value. When converted, no two versions of this random string can be the name number.

I could just generate a number rather than including letters in the original id, but of course that means I have to increase the length of my string, and it's possible that the user of my application may want to type this string, as it identifies his "session" in an application, so I want to keep it short.

So my idea was to build a table like this:

```
A : 1,
B : 2,
C : 3,
D : 4,
E : 5,
F : 6,
G : 7,
H : 8,

... you get the idea ...

5 : 31,
6 : 32,
7 : 33,
8 : 34,
9 : 35
```

And then I'd add all of the numbers up...

`A6HJ92B`:

```
A : 1
6 : 32
H : 8
J : 10
9 : 35
2 : 28
B : 2
```

`1+32+8+10+35+28+2 = 116`

...but I realized this is a flawed idea because many possible strings will "collide" or equal the same number. I need each unique string to equal a unique number.

So even if I multiplied each character's value (`1*32*8*10*35*28*2 = 5,017,600`), I'm thinking there might be possible collisions there too.

**Is there a way to calculate this in a way that eliminates collisions?** If the collisions cant be eliminated, what methods can I use to minimize them?

Comment: I'm thinking I could try something that takes into account the order of the numbers, like `A+6-H*J/9+2*B` or maybe where `n = random number between 1 and 10000`, `(An)(6n)(Hn)(Jn)(9n)(2n)(Bn)` but these seem like 'hacky' solutions and I'm guessing there might be better ways

Comment: Related post on Stack Overflow: *[Is there a simple way to convert a unique string of characters into a unique number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821224)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have $35$ characters, so you can effectively convert the string to an integer in base $35$. It would be better to start counting from $0$ instead of $1$ to get values from $0$ to $34$:

```
A :  0
B :  1
C :  2
 ...
9 : 34
```

Now for a given string $a_6a_5a_4\ldots a_1a_0$, your function can be
$$a_635^6 + a_535^5 + \ldots + a_135 + a_0.$$
Your example of `A6HJ92B` would correspond to:
$$0\cdot35^6 + 31\cdot35^5 + 7\cdot35^4 + 9\cdot35^3 + 34\cdot35^2 + 27\cdot35+1 = 1\ 639\ 110\ 971.$$
Is there a reason you don't include the digit `0`? It would seem more natural to include it (thus counting in base 36) and to order the symbols `0123456789ABC...Z`.

Comment: Yes there was a reason for it. I'm considering that "older folks" might not know the copy/paste function and choose to type the code, and I wanted to avoid confusion between O and zero. I might even do better do exclude both O and zero.

Comment: @Viziionary Ah, I see. In that case, you could consider eliminating other characters as well to avoid confusion (e.g., O/Q, 1/I/L, U/V).

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you Theophile, I needed your answer. However I don't know how you get back your string (A6HJ92B) from 1 639 110 971 ?

Comment: @user217648 Glad to help. To convert back, we first need to know the highest power of $35$ that will fit inside $n = 1 639 110 971$. Using logarithms,
$$\log_{35}n = \frac{\log{n}}{\log{35}} = 5.967\ldots$$
so $n$ is slightly smaller than $35^6$. Now find the largest multiple of $35^5$ that fits inside $n$:
$$\frac{n}{35^5} = 31.2\ldots$$
So we have $n = 31\cdot35^5 + \cdots$. Next subtract to get $n_1 = n - 31\cdot35 = 10 932 846$ and calculate
$$\frac{n_1}{35^4} = 7.28\cdots,$$ so the next coefficient is $7$, etc.

Comment: @user217648 In the original problem, we knew that the code is $7$ characters long, so in fact the first coefficient (corresponding to $35^6$) is $0$, meaning character $A$.

Comment: @user217648 Oops—of course that should be $n_1 = n - 31\cdot35^5$, not $n-31\cdot35$. I hope the rest is clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this java program helps you:**

```
     int i=0;
     int total=1;
     String[] input = new String[35];
     String inputString = "A6HJ92B";
     char[] inputChar = inputString.toCharArray();
     for(char a = 'A' ; a<='Z' ; a++ ){
         i++;
         input[i-1] = a+":"+i;
     }
     for(char b = '1';b<='9';b++){
         i++;
         input[i-1] = String.valueOf(b)+":"+i;
     }

   for(int k=0;k<inputChar.length;k++){
       for(int j = 0;j<input.length;j++){
           if(input[j].charAt(0)==inputChar[k]){

               total*=Integer.parseInt(input[j].substring(input[j].indexOf(':')+1,input[j].length()));
           }
       }
   }  System.out.println(total);
```